# Total energy on island (single electron box), how to derive it?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-circuits, capacitance, semiconductor-physics

I have a basic question about the energy of having $N$ electron on an island for the single electron box.

I am following [this lecture](https://youtu.be/PXVnvKWn5ak?t=1033), where we have the circuit given below.
$C_g$ is the capacitance of the upper capacitor, $C_t$ is the capacitance of the tunnel junction.

We want to calculate the charging energy. It is said that it is equal to:
$$E=\frac{(N|e|-C_g V_g)^2}{2 C}$$
Where $N$ is the total number of electron on the island, $e$ their charge, and $C=C_g+C_t$

My question is: **how do we get to this result** ?

For me the result should be:

$$E= \frac{1}{2} C_g (V_I-V_g)^2+\frac{1}{2} C_t V_I^2=\frac{(N|e|)^2+C_g C_t V_g^2}{2C}$$

[image]

Comment: Which lecturer? Which minute?

Comment: @Qmechanic Sergey Frolov. At 17:13 (the link I provided is at the good minute)

Comment: I'll try to provide an answer later, but for now, I'll just link to the reference I always turn to when trying to understand how dots/islands charge https://www.ftf.lth.se/fileadmin/ftf/Course_pages/FFF042/cb_lecture07.pdf